# Jenkins failing to run after attempting to implement AD login

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins instance that I tried to set up with Active Directory. None of the users could log in with any credentials after, so I went onto the server and removed the Active Directory plugin in an attempt to remove the configuration and rebooted the server. I'm now seeing the following error

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:379)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:43)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:48)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:461)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:327)
Caused: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException:           hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm : hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm
---- Debugging information ----
message             :     hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/securityRealm
line number         : 15
version             : not available
-------------------------------
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:356)
at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:161)
at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:132)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:178)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /data/jenkins/config.xml
at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:181)
at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:161)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3005)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1200(Jenkins.java:304)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$14.run(Jenkins.java:3104)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1068)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:48)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1102)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:904)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

Is there another way to disable all occurrences of the plugin so we can log in?

Comment: `grep` around the config and start editing.

Answer (score 6):

This is likely because your `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` has a section in it that looks like the following:

```
  <securityRealm class="hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm" plugin="active-directory@2.6">
    <domains>
      <hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
        <name>ad.example.com</name>
        <bindPassword>{some obfuscated password here}</bindPassword>
      </hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
    </domains>
    <startTls>true</startTls>
    <groupLookupStrategy>RECURSIVE</groupLookupStrategy>
    <removeIrrelevantGroups>true</removeIrrelevantGroups>
    <tlsConfiguration>TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES</tlsConfiguration>
  </securityRealm>
```

You can gain admin access with the following steps.  Note that this will (temporarily) give admin access to anonymous users, so use with caution!

Shut down Jenkins, remove the above `securityRealm` section from your `config.xml`, and also change the following section:

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

to this:

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Start Jenkins again.  At this point, you can use the web UI to re-install/configure authn/authz plugins.

See also [this question on admin backdoors for Jenkins](https://serverfault.com/questions/885415/jenkins-ldap-plugin-any-way-to-have-a-login-backdoor/885435#885435).